# How to add description for list of columns or tables in Powerbi from csv, excel or db?

Tags: powerbi

In Power Bi, I have long list of tables, fields and I want to add description for each column, measures, tables etc. automatically from other sources instead of writing them manually .

I already have descriptions in a excel file.

`Is there a way to do it by uploading them into the description shown in image below from excel, csv or db or dax  ?`

This will help me in two ways:

1) Any report reader will get to know the description from the report itself.

2) I will also be able to pull descriptions from DAX if needed.

[description image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLKMg.png)

So far I have added manually only but looking for other ways.

Comment: Please give us a bit more information as in: In what visual or table do you intend to store or display the descriptions? What does your data model look like? Do you already have files with descriptions? What code or solutions have you tried? For reference have a look at this ["manual"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @JelleHoekstra 1) I have added image of the `description` field that I am looking to populate. (2) I have 1000's of fields descriptions stored in excel which I would like to add to the columns. (3) I haven't find any code so far  that's why I am asking it here.

Comment: Have you tried scripting it out in [Tabular Editor](https://github.com/otykier/tabulareditor) advanced scripting? The compatibility with Power BI can be spotty, as the AMO libraries that Tabular Editor depends on aren't written for PBI.

Comment: @greggyb No I haven't. I am new to Power Bi and still exploring options like DAX. Would really appreciate if Tabular Editor has some direct solution of doing it.

Comment: DAX cannot be used for metadata operations. Tabular Editor has an [advanced scripting mode](https://github.com/otykier/TabularEditor/wiki/Advanced-Scripting) where you can make programmatic changes to an opened model in a C# script, but support is spotty for PBI models, like I said. To set a measure's description is `Model.Tables["<table>"].Measures["<measurename>"].Description = "<description>";`. Other objects are similar. Anyway, PBI Desktop offers no such metadata programming capabilities. It doesn't look like the PBI Service API offers this sort of functionality in its dataset operations.

Comment: @greggyb Thanks for the suggestions. I think `advanced scripting mode` can help me in this as you suggested above. Thanks for the help again!!